# Docker-compose up for a spring service and a mysql service works, but init.sql does is not loaded and Postman return empty data

Tags: mysql, spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am working for the first time with Docker. In my job, they asked me to deploy a complete application using `docker-compose` and I am learning right now.

I have a docker-compose.yml that starts two services: one for spring and another one for MySQL.

- The one for Spring uses a Dockerfile to build the image.
- The one for MySQL uses the official MySQL image.

I don´t know how to load the `init.sql` to initialize and load data into the database of the MySQL container.

I´ve tried to use another Dockerfile in order to copy init.sql into the MySQL container but,
how do I tell the compose to use it when creating the image or running the container?

This is for a Windows 10 OS Desktop. Docker version 18.09.2. Docker-compose version 1.23.2
Docker Desktop

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    mysql-docker-container:
        image: mysql
        container_name: mysql-docker-container
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
            - MYSQL_USER=user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user
        ports:
            - 2012:3306
        tty: true

    spring-jpa-app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile     
        container_name: spring-jpa-app
        links:
            - mysql-docker-container:mysql-docker-container
        depends_on:
            - mysql-docker-container
        ports: 
            - 8087:8080
        tty: true
        restart: always
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
ADD app-1.0.0.jar app-1.0.0.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app-1.0.0.jar"]
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-docker-container:2012/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user
spring.jpa.database=database
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
logging.file=log/log.log
logging.level.org.springframework=info
logging.level.orghibernate=info
```

Docker Desktop running

Opened `Git Bash` as administrator

```
docker-machine ls
NAME  ACTIVE DRIVER  STATE     URL                       DOCKER
app    *      hyperv Running   tcp://172.18.67.35:2376   v19.03.0
```

In the app folder, where is located /src

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
BUILD SUCCESS
```

In the app folder where is located **application.properties**, **app.jar**, **docker-compose.yml**, **Dockerfile** and **init.sql**

```
docker-compose up --build
```

**Postman**

URL = http://172.18.67.35:8087

```
POST {{url}}/login
{   
      "Authorization": "gnioengrlnkwejnR",
      "username": "Administrator",
      "role": "ADMIN",
      "id": "1"
}
```

```
GET {{url}}/listAllCenters
[]
```

Returns empty because **init.sql** is not being loaded

PD: Also, if I open a new git Bash as Administrator and do

```
docker ps -a
```

I do not get the containers running so I cannot know container's ID to enter the MySQL container.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a volume to copy the sql.init to your db continer:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    mysql-docker-container:
        image: mysql
        container_name: mysql-docker-container
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
            - MYSQL_USER=user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user
        ports:
            - 2012:3306
        volumes:
            - /bath/to/file/on/host/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        tty: true
        network_mode: "host"

    spring-jpa-app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile     
        container_name: spring-jpa-app
        links:
            - mysql-docker-container:mysql-docker-container
        depends_on:
            - mysql-docker-container
        ports: 
            - 8087:8080
        tty: true
        restart: always
        network_mode: "host"
```

see [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) and search for "Initializing a fresh instance"

on the other hand you need to use network to setup the connection between the containers - see the compose file above-
and you need to change you configs to

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:2012/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it did the same, works but in Postman returns empty, and the init.sql inserts many data, I mean it is correct, the problem is not the init.sql